# How can I make "favorites" in Windows 7 Explorer always fixed on the top of the left pane?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In Windows Vista, "Favorites" in left pane is always fix on the top of the list, so it is always accessable; but in Windows 7, if folder tree goes to long, Favorites will disappear from the screen makes it completely unusable. Is there a way that can make it always fixed on the top position like in Vista?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You only need to scroll the sidepanel up to see the Favourites again.  The little arrow next to it toggles whether it is extended or collapsed, and this setting sticks.

This is the intended behaviour and there is no way to change it.

Comment: Well.
I know I "only need to" scroll up. But this is very annoying, because it's not simple and fast, but this thing should be and was very simple and fast.
Yet another "what the hell are they thinking" stuff in Windows 7.
Thanks for your answer anyway.